# trouble installing snow leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, leopard

My optical drive is no longer working and I'm having trouble updating from leopard to snow leopard I got this message when I tried to install

> "To install Mac OS X, use Disk utility to burn this disk image to a DVD and run this application again"

I've tried using disc utility to copy an image of the disk and mounting and to try to trick my mac to thinking its a disk, then tried rebooting the mac while holding down the option button but nothing but the hard drive comes up.

Does anybody else have any suggestions?

Is there some kind of command that can make my computer recognize it as a disk?

I have also tried using remote disk from my sisters macbook pro to install the software that had already had a disk image copied & burned to a disk.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *restore* Snow Leopard image in Disk Utility to *GUID partitioned* drive or flash stick. Only after that it will be possible to boot from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to boot from a disk image file of the Snow Leopard install DVD, that is not going to work.

You are going to need to make a new empty partition on your mac or on a boot-able external drive, eg a USB thumb drive, etc.

1. Use disk utility and make sure that the new partition you make has a GUID partition theme.
2. Once you have that set up now you can restore the Snow Leopard disk image file to that new empty drive partition using disk utility.

The Snow leopard install partition should be a boot-able start up option after performing the preceding.